# Bootstrap Grid from top right to bottom on Mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Scenario :

I have a form, and some additional "add on" content I want to go to the bottom on xs, s, and float right and top on m and lg.

E.g.  On Desktop :

[image]

On Phone :

[image]

Is there any way to accomplish this with bootstrap?  Ignore the offsets due to the images, I'm just worried about column ordering and getting the column E to float right and go to the top when I have enough space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below fiddle. Try to execute on the bottom itself. And then try to execute it again using full screen.

You can do this way:

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css");

.col-md-8 .col-md-12 {background: #99f;}
.col-md-4 .col-md-12 {background: #f99;}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">A</div>
        <div class="col-md-12">B</div>
        <div class="col-md-12">C</div>
        <div class="col-md-12">D</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">E</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, I didn't think of creating two external container div's to do the shuck and jive.  thanks!